# Trouble Getting Value From JSON Query

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to read data from a json api. My code is below and I have also included a snippet of what the json data looks like. I'm trying to get the current conversion rate for GBP in my example. My code is getting stuck at the line in bold.  This is my first time working with JSON so is there an easy way to return only the value for GBP from this data?

```
public class Currency
    {
        public List<string> rates { get; set; }
    }

    public decimal convertCurrency(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        decimal rate = 0;
        string url = String.Format("https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id={0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OpenExchangeRate_AppID"]);

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(url)))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            **List<Currency> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Currency>>(json);**

            foreach (var item in items[0].rates)
            {
                if (item == toCurrency.ToUpper())
                {
                    // currency matches
                    rate = Convert.ToDecimal(item);
                }
            }
        }

        return rate;
    }
```

{

```
"disclaimer": "Exchange rates are provided for informational purposes only, and do not constitute financial advice of any kind. Although every attempt is made to ensure quality, NO guarantees are given whatsoever of accuracy, validity, availability, or fitness for any purpose - please use at your own risk. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the Terms and Conditions of Service, available at: https://openexchangerates.org/terms/",   
"license": "Data sourced from various providers with public-facing APIs; copyright may apply; resale is prohibited; no warranties given of any kind. Bitcoin data provided by http://coindesk.com. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the License Agreement available at: https://openexchangerates.org/license/",   
"timestamp": 1415858442,   
"base": "USD",   
"rates": {
"AED": 3.672917,
"AFN": 57.690401,
"GBP": 0.634097   
} 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No I insert a breakpoint at the following line and it never hits it.

Comment: do you ever call that function?

Comment: Yes I can see the json data at the previous line where it converts it from the stream to a json string and I can see the data is there and correct. I did a foreach on the items in the list and that works but when I changed it to items[0].rates it stopped working and I'm not sure why

Comment: Is the posted definition of `Currency` the complete code?  It may not be deserializing properly because it doesn't have properties for the other items in the JSON ("disclaimer", "license", etc).  Also note that you might need a sub-class for "rates" that holds the country code *and* the exchange rate (JSON is not something I work with a lot, so I could be wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Currency
    {
        public Rates rates { get; set; }

        public class Rates
        {
            public decimal AED { get; set; }
            public decimal AFN { get; set; }
            public decimal GBP { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

get rate like this

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Currency>(json);
        rate = items.rates.GBP;
```

Answer (score 1):

For future benefit of OP and other readers, there is an online utility that will allow you to paste JSON and it will generate C# classes for you - [Jonathan Keith's jsontocsharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

The result for the JSON above is very similiar (and functionally equivalent to) feiyun's answer:

Input JSON:

```
{"disclaimer": "Exchange rates are provided for informational purposes only, and do not constitute financial advice of any kind. Although every attempt is made to ensure quality, NO guarantees are given whatsoever of accuracy, validity, availability, or fitness for any purpose - please use at your own risk. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the Terms and Conditions of Service, available at: https://openexchangerates.org/terms/",   
 "license": "Data sourced from various providers with public-facing APIs; copyright may apply; resale is prohibited; no warranties given of any kind. Bitcoin data provided by http://coindesk.com. All usage is subject to your acceptance of the License Agreement available at: https://openexchangerates.org/license/",   
 "timestamp": 1415858442,   
 "base": "USD",   
 "rates": { "AED": 3.672917,
            "AFN": 57.690401,
            "GBP": 0.634097   
 } 
}
```

Output from jsontocsharp:

```
public class Rates
{

    public double AED { get; set; }
    public double AFN { get; set; }
    public double GBP { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{

    public string disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Rates rates { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! I'm glad I know about that